# how to build a project folder manager n pyqt5 qtreewidget with drag and drop

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5, qtreeview, qtreewidget

I am building a kind of qtreewidget whch I can control the contents of a folder with drag and drop in my tree.

I looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44077263/12102537) answer for loading the content of a folder and setting icon for them. And then I used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47118313/12102537) answer for adding drag and drop, but the problem is if I drop an item on another item which is for a file the first item comes inside the second item. It means yo move a file in another file and that is impossible.

So I summarize my problem. I need to build a qtreewidget which I can control the content of my folder with drag and drop.
What should I do?

Comment: Please provide a [*minimal, reproducible* example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). It can be done, but we need to understand how you've implemented the tree widget so far.

Comment: I editted the second "this" to the second link. read these two links to understand what am I saying. But I want to edit the second link to can copy and paste files too.

Comment: You might have applied some changes to those examples, and we cannot "imagine" how you implemented them. Provide an MRE.